# how to toggle only one element of a loop in a Django template using JavaScript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I'm trying to implement a toggle to display a hidden DIV for every element in my loop statement on a Django template. Problem is I only manage to make it work just on the first element of the loop, or in all of them at once (one buttom triggers every hidden DIV to show).
How can I make this possible using vanilla JS or in worst case scenario Jquery?

here is the html in my template

```
{% for comment in comments%}
            <div class="comment">
                <p><strong>{{comment.author}} {% if comment.author == article.author%}[Seller]{% endif %}</strong> said:</p>
                <p>{{comment.commentary}} {% if user.is_authenticated and article.status == "Active" and article.author == user %}<button id="test" class="test" onclick="myFunction()">Reply>></button></p>
                <div class="reply_box_container" id="reply_box_container" style="display:none">
                    <p><strong>Reply:</strong></p>
                    <form>
                        <div id="reply_textarea_container"><textarea  name="comment_textarea" rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Write your reply here"></textarea></div>
                        <div id="reply_btn_container"><button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="comment_btn">submit</button></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                {% endif %} 
                    {% if reply%}
                        <span class="reply">
                            <p><strong>{{article.author}}</strong> replied:</p>
                            <p>{{reply}}</p>
                        </span>
                    {% endif %}
                    <hr></hr>
            </div>  
        {% endfor %}
```

and here the Jquery I tried to use:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".test").click(function(){
    $(".reply_box_container").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So, You want `only one element of Your Model` ?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right path, the reason why it's only working with the first element or all elements it's because you have the same id in each one, try giving a unique id such as `id="reply_box_container-{{ forloop.counter }}"`. Bear in mind that the `id="test"` should be unique too, and you can pass the counter in the `click` function.
For more reference about the loop counter in Django [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
{% for comment in comments%}
    <!-- here is your stuff -->

    <!-- just change the classes, make them like this -->

    <div class="iWantToToggleThis{{comment.id}}"> stuff </div>   
    <!-- this way every object will have different class -->

    <button class="btn{{comment.id}}" > button </button>
    <!-- this way every button will have different class -->



 <!-- then put this script in for loop -->

<script>
    $(".btn{{comment.id}}").on("click", function() {
        $(".iWantToToggleThis{{comment.id}}").toggle();
    });
</script>



{% endfor %}
```

And vala itz done,
And also better late than NEVER.